# Random guessing game stuck

Tags: c

I am practicing the basics of C programming using the book SAMS Teach yourself C in 21 days.

On one of the type and run sections, they have the find the number (or guess the number) program, I typed it and run it, however the program on the console gets stuck showing the following:

Getting a random number

I waited for some time but nothing happens, even pushing some keys it doesn't do anything.

I am not familiar yet with the srand(), time() and rand() routines so I don't know how to fix it and make it run properly.

below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NO 0
#define YES 1

int main (void)
{
    int guess_value = -1;
    int number;
    int nbr_of_guesses;
    int done = NO;


    printf("\nGetting a random number\n");

    /*use the time to seed the random number generator*/

    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); 
    number = rand();


    nbr_of_guesses = 0;

    while (done == NO);
    {
        printf("\nPick a number between 0 and %d>", RAND_MAX);
        scanf("%d", &guess_value); /*get a number*/

        nbr_of_guesses++;

        if (number == guess_value)
        {
            done = YES;
        }
        else
            if (number < guess_value)
            {
                printf("\nYou guessed high!");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nYou guessed low!");
            }

    }

    printf("\nCongratulations! you guessed right in %d Guesses!", nbr_of_guesses);
    printf("\n\nThe number was %d", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the `while` statement. That'll fix it for sure.

Comment: Wow, I read to much codes today that I actually missed that one, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see 2 problems.

There is a semicolon on the while that's causing the program to hang.

There is nothing that ensures that the output buffer is flushed before you read the guess.

I have put comments to indicate the code changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NO 0
#define YES 1

int main (void)
{
    int guess_value = -1;
    int number;
    int nbr_of_guesses;
    int done = NO;


    printf("\nGetting a random number\n");

    /*use the time to seed the random number generator*/

    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); 
    number = rand();


    nbr_of_guesses = 0;

    while (done == NO)   // Removed the ;
    {
        printf("\nPick a number between 0 and %d>", RAND_MAX);
        fflush(stdout);  // stdout is line buffered, and since there is no \n in the printf we need an explicit call to fflush,
        scanf("%d", &guess_value); /*get a number*/

        nbr_of_guesses++;

        if (number == guess_value)
        {
            done = YES;
        }
        else
            if (number < guess_value)
            {
                printf("\nYou guessed high!");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nYou guessed low!");
            }

    }

    printf("\nCongratulations! you guessed right in %d Guesses!", nbr_of_guesses);
    printf("\n\nThe number was %d", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not a standard C.

Comment: @macfij Thanks, it is supposed to be fflush(stdout), changed it!